# Understanding Output From DFT

Tags: noise, phase, spectrum-analyzer

I should preface this by saying I'm a novice at all of this: I'm designing a system (using a stand-alone FPGA board combined with an ADC that offloads data to a GPU) that is supposed to look for high Q signals embedded in white noise. Currently, I'm at the very beginning of the testing stage, and I have a few fundamental questions about what I'm seeing at the output.

As a test of the system, I've injected a -27 dBm (~30mVpp), 420 MHz sine wave from a signal generator into the system. The signal is digitized by a 2 GS/s, 8-bit ADC (externally clocked) with a 20 dB front-end amplifier. I take 2<sup>26</sup> samples, do a DFT (of the same length), and compute the power spectrum. Below is the output. Note, that I have applied a Kaiser window to the data before taking the DFT.

[image: DFT of 420 MHz sine wave]

There is an obvious peak at 420 MHz (along with a few spurs), but the amplitude is way down from expected (-7 dBm). Things start to look even stranger as I zoom in. Taking a 4 MHz span around the central peak produces the following:

[image: DFT of 420 MHz sine wave zoomed in to look at 418 to 422 MHz]

This looks nothing like the nice smooth peak I expected. And zooming in even further makes this point clearer:

[image: DFT of 420 MHz sine wave zoomed in to look at 419.5 to 420.5 MHz]

My questions are both fundamental:

1. I think I am seeing significant amounts of both phase noise and scalloping loss. Are these the right words or is it something else?
2. My peak is incredibly broad. I have checked on a commercial spectrum analyzer (with poorer resolution but over the same span) and do not find that the peak is anywhere near this broad. Could phase noise be causing this?

Big thanks for any insight you may have.

Edit
In response to a question about repeating taking data with a lower order Kaiser, I've done just that and attached the plot below. In this example, the window is still a Kaiser but with α = 1 (it was 14 before). The top subplot shows the span from 418-422 MHz. The bottom subplot is a zoom in from 419.5-420.5MHz. Looks like the scalloping is greatly diminished. That gives me a rabbit hole to jump down.

[image: DFT of 420 MHz sine wave windowed by an α = 1 Kaiser.]

End of edit

Comment: It seems like the properties of high  α for the Kaiser window. Can you reduce this towards 0 and repeat?

Comment: To get the kind of output you want, you need to digitize an integer number of the input’s cycles, so the  total sampling time can not be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: Have you looked at the input data? Are you sure that you don't have clipping? What is the amplitude of the sine wave in the input data?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you for the suggestion. I edited the post. It looks like the scalloping loss is dramatically reduced. That gives me something to go read about now. Appreciate it.

Comment: @user69795 I'm okay with the peak not being a delta-function, but the peak looks like it's ~100kHz wide and the amplitude is 40 dB down from what I'd expect it to be, which doesn't pass the sniff test to me.

Comment: @Mattman944 The input going into the ADC (after the amplifier) is 300 mVpp (30mVpp before the amplifier). Full scale on the ADC is 950mV. I've also checked the digitized data and it doesn't looked clipped (on either side).

Comment: How good (pure) is your 420 MHz source?  FRom your second plot, it looks like there's a 500 KHz square wave in there (peaks at 500 KHz, 1500 KHz, etc away from the center).

Comment: @SteveSh I've looked at the injected signal on a commercial spectrum analyzer and do not see those peaks at all. Doing a narrow span scan I find that the injected signal falls off by 60 dB within 1 kHz of the injected signal's peak.

Comment: So, how pure is the 2GHz sampling clock?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you for the comment. That was a really helpful rabbit hole to jump down. The clock signal looks good (again, measuring on a commercial spectrum analyzer), but I'm nearly certain that my CPU can't keep up with the data being sent to it and is dropping packets. If I slow the clock down to 1 GHz, I see a much better looking signal (a spike that falls off quickly and has approximately the expected amplitude).  Still lots of phase noise, but I have a feeling that'll be a longstanding issue. Much appreciated.